# How to do Regular Expression or JSON XPATH expression for JSON

Tags: json, xpath, jmeter

Could some advise me  How to do Regular Expression or JSON XPATH expression for JSON  for   "GLDefaultId" and  "GLDefaultValueId":1 in the following Request POST DATA

**Request:**
POST data:
{"GLDefaultId":0,"ProjectId":1806,"CoaMainId":10,"UserId":33,"Notes":"","PRO_GLDefaultValue":[{"GLDefaultValueId":0,"GLDefaultId":0,"SegmentId":16,"Alias":"ACT","SegmentType":"DETAIL","FunctionTypeId":0,"Value":"&&&","Mask":"&&&","IsRequired":true,"LastModified":null,"IsCoaRequired":true},{"GLDefaultValueId":0,"GLDefaultId":0,"SegmentId":17,"Alias":"ST","SegmentType":"SET","FunctionTypeId":0,"Value":"&&","Mask":"&&","IsRequired":false,"LastModified":null,"IsCoaRequired":false}]}

**Response:**
{"$id":"1","GLDefaultId":1,"ProjectId":1806,"CoaMainId":10,"Notes":"","PRO_GLDefaultValue":[{"$id":"2","GLDefaultValueId":1,"GLDefaultId":1,"Alias":"ACT","FunctionTypeId":0,"Value":"&&&","SegmentId":16,"IsRequired":true,"ModifiedOn":"2017-08-11T17:27:26.562989-07:00","ModifiedBy":33,"PRO_GLDefault":{"$ref":"1"},"LastModified":null},{"$id":"3","GLDefaultValueId":2,"GLDefaultId":1,"Alias":"ST","FunctionTypeId":0,"Value":"&&","SegmentId":17,"IsRequired":false,"ModifiedOn":"2017-08-11T17:27:26.562989-07:00","ModifiedBy":33,"PRO_GLDefault":{"$ref":"1"},"LastModified":null}]}

Comment: I seriously  tried  but couldn't find the solution

Comment: Are you looking to extract those properties from the strings?

Comment: @ALI ,yes  .GLDefaultId" and "GLDefaultValueId":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `$.*[*].GLDefaultId` and `$.*[*].GLDefaultValueId` as JSON paths to extract the values.

Comment: What are you developing in?

Comment: Trying to find  Json extractor for the dynamic values of a sampler Response

Comment: It's complains as Exception: Failed to parse SliceOperation: :  when  I tried $.*[:].GLDefaultId

Comment: Try `[*]` instead of `[:]`.